# Maximizing function involving factorials and ceiling

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, optimization, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am trying to find the maximum of the following function (mapping $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge0})$:

$$\max_{\alpha\in[0,1]} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^2~ \prod_{j=i}^n \frac{j+1}{\lceil{\alpha j}\rceil}}{\sum_{i=1}^n \lceil\alpha i\rceil^2~ \prod_{j=i}^n \frac{j+1}{\lceil{\alpha j}\rceil} + \prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j+1}{\lceil{\alpha j}\rceil}},$$

ideally in the limit when $n\rightarrow +\infty$. This number is the best achievable price-of-anarchy in affine congestion games and was first introduced [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.3220&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (page 89) in a different context.
As $n$ grows large, this number approaches
$$2.01206694843168.$$

**Q:** Finding this number in closed form is very dear to me. Any suggestions/ideas on how to proceed?

**Edit:** Here is a plot of the function for $n=60$ (discretization in $\alpha$ is $10^{-6}$)

[image]

Comment: Looking at the graphs, it seems that the max is found with $\alpha \in \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{7} \right)$. If this is true, then the maximum value is given by a bunch of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @Varun, thanks for giving it a thought! Do you have any further insight going beyond the “looking at the graph” argument? Also it does not seem trivial to me to compute the value of the function, even under the assumption that the optimal $\alpha$ is known. Where did you get the hypergeometric functions from?

Comment: Once I guessed that $\alpha = \frac{1}{4} + \epsilon$, I just did a bunch of pretty simple manipulations and then plugged it into Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you @varun. Did you get the same values of the function for all the choices of $\alpha$ in the open interval you mention? What limiting value do you get?

Comment: Yeah, I get the same value for the whole interval. The limiting value is given by a ratio of two sums of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @VarunVejalla would you mind posting the expression you get?