# Asymptotic behaviour of infinite product of ceilings $\lceil\alpha\rceil \lceil2\alpha\rceil \lceil3\alpha\rceil\dots$, $\alpha\in(0,1)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

I am interested in computing the value of a complex expression (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583353/maximizing-function-involving-factorials-and-ceiling)) containing the following building block

$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j}{\lceil{\alpha j}\rceil},
$$

and its partial product starting from $j=i$, where $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is a parameter. I am interested in the behavior as $n\rightarrow\infty$. While for all $\alpha\in(0,1)$, the above expression is unbounded as $n$ grows, I would want to understand the asymptotic behavior of this infinite product parametrized by $\alpha$.

- Has anyone ever encountered similar expressions?
- Any ideas of how to get the asymptotic?
- Also pointers to connections with other functions in combinatorics/number theory would be useful.

**Note:** the fundamental difficulty arises from understanding the behavior of the term on the denominator:
$$
\lceil\alpha\rceil \lceil2\alpha\rceil \lceil3\alpha\rceil ...\lceil n\alpha\rceil,
$$
as the numerator can be simply written as $(n+1)!$

Thank you :-)

Comment: The numerator in the other question is $j+1$. Should that be the numerator in this question too?

Comment: @VarunVejalla I changed it to j only for aesthetic reasons, but the question remain the same: if we can understand the asymptotic of this expression with j at the numerator, we can trivially extract the asymptotic with j+1 too.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\alpha j\le\lceil \alpha j\rceil<\alpha j+1$$

and

$$\alpha^nn!\le\prod_{j=1}^n\lceil\alpha j\rceil<\prod_{j=1}^n(\alpha j+1).$$

Then
$$\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\alpha+\dfrac1j\right)<\prod_{j=1}^n\left(1+\dfrac1j\right)=n+1$$

so

$$\alpha^nn!\le\prod_{j=1}^n\lceil\alpha j\rceil<(n+1)!$$

Comment: Hi @yves, thank you for starting the discussion, I think your observation is a good start. At the same time I don't think it fully settles the question of quantifying the asymptotic behavior as there is a slack factor of $n+1$. More formally, we can not conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\prod_{j=1}^n\lceil \alpha j \rceil}{\alpha^n n!}=const,$$ and similarly for $\alpha^n(n+1)!$. For the question I am interested in see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583353/maximizing-function-involving-factorials-and-ceiling), we need a more refined analysis.

Comment: @Bazinga: I know.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of utilizing the same approach used to derive the Stirling approximate of the factorial, see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). The idea is that of looking at $$\log\left(\prod_{j=1}^n \lceil \alpha j\rceil\right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \log(\lceil \alpha j \rceil) $$ and then connect this with the integral $$\int_1^n \log(\lceil \alpha x \rceil) dx,$$ but I do not get much further than here.

Comment: If $n = 1$ and $\alpha = 0.1$, $\prod_{j=1}^n \lceil \alpha j \rceil = 1$, but $\alpha^n (n+1)! = 0.2$, so I don't think the upper bound is correct. I think the correct upper bound is $(n+1)\cdot n!$

Comment: @VarunVejalla: you are quite right, $\alpha^n$ is extra. Thanks for pointing. This makes the bracketing even less tight.

Comment: Actually, that can be restricted even more to $n!$, because $\prod_{j=1}^n \lceil 1\cdot j \rceil = \prod_{j=1}^n j = n!$.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at a simple case, and it's already fairly subtle. For example, say $\alpha=0.5$. It is not difficult to show that
$\prod_{j=1}^n \lceil \alpha j \rceil = (n/2)! (n/2)!$ when $n$ is even. In this case, using Stirling approximants, we get
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{\lceil \alpha j \rceil}=\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}\sim \frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}},
$$
also verified numerically. The reasoning (based on the explicit computation of the product of the ceilings) can be extended with a bit of care to any $\alpha=1/q$ with $q$ integer, but brakes down already with $\alpha = p/q$, and $p,q$ integers.